# Change image source using C#

Tags: c#, image, xaml, bitmap

I'm creating a windows store app and was wondering how to change the image source using C# I have included the following directive;

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
```

and this is the line I have to try and change the image

```
cloud.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/cloud1.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

cloud is the name of the image tag and cloud1 is the source I want to change it to.. but it gives me this error...

```
"The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri"
```

Any help appreciated! thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cloud.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/cloud1.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

instead.

Comment: I had to change "UriKind.Relative" to "UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute" but with the inclusion of ms-appx it worked! thanks, how come that worked? what did it actually do?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781229.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965322(v=win.10).aspx)